# order filenames according to numbers in them, in bash

Tags: bash, filenames, renaming

I need to convert a bunch of files into a different format in bash. my filenames are like this:

```
file_STUDY_6.nii
file_STUDY_7.nii
file_STUDY_8.nii
```

but they don't always start with 6, so I need it to be flexible. I want to be able to find all the files that contain "STUDY", and be able to rename the one with the lowest # (here, 6) as `study_run1`.

I know I can access the files by doing the following:

```
for files in *STUDY*.nii; do
    echo files
done
```

but I'm not sure how to name the first one `study_run1`, the second `study_run2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this loop in `bash` using [*process substitution*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
i=0    
while read -r f; do
   echo mv "$f" "study_run$((++i))"
done < <(printf "%s\n" *STUDY*.nii | sort -t_ -nk3)
```

**Output:**

```
mv file_STUDY_6.nii study_run1
mv file_STUDY_7.nii study_run2
mv file_STUDY_8.nii study_run3
```

Once verified, you can remove `echo` from above script.

PS: On many systems `printf "%s\n" *STUDY*.nii` will give filenames already sorted alphabetically.